# Engine modifications when using waste vegetable oil

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, conversion

I'd like to ask what engine modifications is needed for converting a car from B7 diesel to used vegetable oil (uvo) ?

I have an old BMW from 2013 and has bought filters to externally clean the uvo down to 1 micron.

I've heard that due to a different pH, the fuel tubes would disintegrate using uvo. Is that true and what tubes would be sufficient to use then?

I'm not looking for solutions to make a an additional fuel heater yet because summer is coming. But I'd like to be aware of certain elemental technical issues that I could be avoiding when using uvo.

Sincerely

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The only way I've heard of using vegetable oil is to convert it to biodiesel, which is done external of the vehicle. Is this what you've done?

Comment: [This article might be a good primer.](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/fuel-efficiency/fuel-consumption/vegetable-oil-fuel.htm)